# In Azure Table Storage, is it possible to query a substring of a property with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage

In my Azure Table I have a **string property** called `"Labels"` that looks something like this (A Json serialization of List):

```
["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
```

Is it possible to query the table for all the entries that contain the substring `"value3"` in the Labels property?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like wildcard search `eg message like '%SysFn%'`, it is not feasible at this moment, You can find all the supported operations below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN

[image]
Yes, you can filter by any attribute. However please keep in mind that only PartitionKey and RowKey are indexed so any query operation which doesn't include at least PartitionKey will result in full table scan. This will become an issue if your table contains lots of entities.

Hope it helps.